# Translatation failing for CSRF token

Tags: symfony, translation

I have a problem. In my form the text **The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.** is not translating to French. I have the following in my `translations/validator.fr.yml` file:

```
The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.: 'Actualisez le formulaire svp'
```

I am using Symfony 2.7.

Comment: Are other translations working?  Symfony already has a default translation message for French: `Le jeton CSRF est invalide. Veuillez renvoyer le formulaire.` Are you seeing this, or are you seeing the English translation?

Comment: for this projet i have no translation. I want the french translation

Comment: Right - so do you have the locale set to French when you're trying to have this translation?

Comment: in config.yml i have  parameters:
    locale: fr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading your comments, if you want your translations to be in French you can [set a default locale](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#setting-a-default-locale) for your application, and you must also enable the `translator` in your configuration.  In your `app/config/config.yml` you would put:

```
parameters:
    locale: fr

framework:
    translator:     { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    default_locale: "%locale%"
```

The `translator` line is commented out when you first install Symfony (see the master [app/config/config.yml](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/blob/master/app/config/config.yml) file).

Comment: i add this in the config.yml, i remove the cache and i have the same response: The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.

Comment: updated my answer, translations are not enabled by default in Symfony so you'll have to enable them

Comment: happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. if this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.